# Footnote is on wrong page ... due to side-caption table?

Tags: tables, footnotes, page, sidecap

In the example at the bottom, the footnote appears on the wrong page. Any help on how to fix this is much appreciated! I have the suspicion that it may relate to the side-caption table (`SCtable`). If I convert this to a standard table, the footnote appears on the right page. However, I would like to keep the side-caption table.

The PDF output looks like:
[image]

The footnote should appear on the first page but does appear on the second page.

If I insert a `\newpage` before the first section (where a page break is anyway), then the footnote appears at the correct position. However, I don't want to hard code the page break because the layout may still change.
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help on how to fix this issue.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[width=16cm,vmarginratio={3:4},top=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[innercaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1.5ex}
\onehalfspacing


\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

\lipsum[5]

\lipsum*[3-4]

\lipsum*[3]\footnote{I would like to have the footnote text on the same page as the footnote mark.}

% \newpage  % IF I UN-COMMENT THE NEWPAGE COMMAND, THE FOOTNOTE IS ON THE CORRECT PAGE

\section{New Section}

\begin{SCtable}[][tb]
  \begin{tabular}{ccc} \hline
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C}\\
    1 & 2 & 3\\
    4 & 5 & 6\\  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Caption for Table}
\end{SCtable}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: My gut tells me that it's not ideal to put a float right after `\section`. If you move `\lipsum[1]` before the float then the footnote is placed correctly.

Comment: Intersestingly enough, I can't reproduce "If I convert this to a standard table, the footnote appears on the right page. ". If I replace `SCtable` with `table`, the footnote text is still on the wrong page.

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention what @leandriis pointed out: I also get the same output with normal tables, and also removing `footmisc`.

Comment: @campa: I confirm that the footnote is correctly placed when moving `\lipsum[1]` before the table. It would be great to hear an explanation of why that is. I have such situations a lot and would like to know possible side effects/disadvantages. @leandriis: I checked again: If I change `SCtable` to `table` (I also need to remove `[]` to have the correct syntax), then the footnote appears on the first page.

Comment: I made a shorter example and added it to an issue in the latex github: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/399#issuecomment-749482180

Comment: I checked the change from `SCtable` to `table` again. Now I can confirm that it does not affect the footnote position. (Don't know why it appeared differently to me before. Maybe I changed something else together with the table. Sorry for the confusion.) I don't know what I should do according to good tex.sx syle? Should I edit my question and the title accordingly, as the problem does not seem related to the sidecap?